# Trigger para um Select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, trigger

Gostaria de saber se é possível executar uma Trigger quando um SELECT for realizado em uma determinada tabela, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Conversa" (
  "idConversa" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "idEmissorConversa" INT NOT NULL,
  "idReceptorConversa" INT NOT NULL,
  "mensagemConversa" VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  "statusConversa" INT NOT NULL,
  "horaConversa" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("idConversa")
```

Essa é a tabela, o conceito dela é criar um Chat, onde vou guardar o Id de quem enviou  a mensagem, ID de quem recebeu a mensagem, o statusConversa seria o item no qual eu queria alterar com a Trigger, pois:

```
statusConversa = 0 -- Significa que a mensagem não foi lida(carregada)
statusConversa = 1 -- Significa que a mensagem foi lida(carregada)
```

Então, quando um SELECT for realizado nessa mensagem, a Trigger deve alterar o statusConversa para 1. Para que posteriormente, quando for verificar via AJAX se há uma mensagem nova, ele vai buscar pelas mensagem com statusConversa = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possivel usar um trigger para um select.

Talvez voce pudesse usar um SELECT FOR UPDATE assim

```
 SELECT * FROM Conversa FOR UPDATE;
 UPDATE Conversa SET statusConversa = 1;
```

Comment: Neste caso todos os itens que vierem desse select terão seus statusConversa setados como 1, mesmo que já esteja como 1, correto?

Comment: sim, mas você pode enviar a timestamp da ultima conversa no cliente(browser?) e assim retornaria o resultado certo também. Não sei se é eficiente este método

Comment: É mesmo, poderia pegar o ultimo timestamp adicionado no bloco do chat, e comparar com o ultimo do select, mas dai eu teria de listar apenas os após(mais novos) desse timestamp, teria como? (o problema é que nunca trabalhei muito a fundo com timestamp, por isso estou meio perdido nas comparações dele, e acho mais fácil fazer pelo statusConversa...